# In simple-webpack template for vue, where build.js comes from?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I’ve just created a [Vue](https://vuejs.org) project based on the simple webpack template using `vue init webpack-simple myproject` CLI command. In the `index.html` I can see this:

```
<html lang="en">
  [...]
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I run the dev server like this:

```
$ npm run dev

Project is running at http://localhost:8081/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html
```

From what I understand about webpack, it bundles all JS libraries and puts them into `build.js` file (just what it says in the output above). However, there is no `dist/build.js` file anywhere in the project dir!

Can anyone explain what’s happening here? Note that when I ran `npm run build`, the build.js appeared as expected. How come that the dev setup works without it, if `index.html` expects it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a question about [Webpack Dev Server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server), not Vue. (If you look at your package.json, you'll see that `npm run dev` is an alias for `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`)

When you're running WDS, it creates the bundle (in this case build.js) and [serves it from memory](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server#content-base). It does not save it to your project. (That comes later, when you do `npm run build`).